# inexpensive soundproofing material

Tags: noise-reduction, noise, damping

I know there's professional grade noise damping material but if I'm on a budget, what other options are there? I've heard of denim, roofing shingles and just cloth in general. But what other options are there for the budget foley room?

Answer (score 6):

If you have 70 dollars to spare, you can get 6 2' x 4' uncovered Rockwool panels. These are huge, and it's a lot of them. All that's left for you to do is wrap them in cloth and frame them. The difference between this option and a 20-30 dollar solution is far more than the 50 dollars you might save.

The following is what I purchased for my studio:
http://www.atsacoustics.com/item--Roxul-Rockboard-60-Case-of-6--RB60.html

Make sure you read up on what the needs will be for your own room. You may need a less or more dense fiber.

http://www.atsacoustics.com/cat--DIY-Acoustic-Materials--102.html

Answer (score 2):

Be very clear about whether you are

- isolating the foley room from outside noise

or

- absorbing reverb/acoustics

They are different problems with different solutions

Answer (score 1):

Rockwool is the most common budget acoustic dampening.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a combination of sheets of fibreglass and Rockwool.

Answer (score 1):

I'll second Iain's comment. I wanted to save a few bob by making my own panels for my studio. They're not tuned to any frequencies as I simply wanted to deaden the reverb in my 4m2 room. Happily turned out really well and my work translates rather splendidly to larger "proper" mix studios.

http://ianpalmersound.com/2011/06/06/d-i-y/

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend rockwool panels wich you can put in a wood frame covered with fabric. It's not very expensive, it's modular and works quite well. I have a PDF tutorial where you can see how to make them, but it is in spanish. If you are interested I can translate ir for you.